# Wrong code Beamer

Tags: beamer

Can you help me please! what's wrong with my code ? I am a beginner!
work not finished!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamersize{text margin left= 0.5cm ,text margin right=0.5cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin top= 0.5cm ,text margin bottom=0.5cm}
\definecolor{trustcolor}{rgb}{0.22,.26,.64}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sommaire}
\tableofcontents[currentsection, 
pausesubsections]
\end{frame}
}
\title{Les Statistiques}
\author{}
\institute{Lyc\'{e}e Agricole Douai}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%premier frame


\titlepage
\end{frame}%1

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]% 2
\frametitle{Introduction }


Dans tout ce chapitre,nous prendrons comme exemple les 4 s\'{e}ries suivantes :
\begin{exampleblock}%le premier block
{\underline{S\'{e}rie A}:Un chimiste a relev\'{e} la temp\'{e}rature d'un liquide lors d'une exp\'{e}rience.\\
Il a obtenu les r\'{e}sultas suivants:\\[0.5cm]}

 \begin{center
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}  61& 62& 63& 64& 68& 71& 73& 77& 80\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{exampleblock}




\begin{exampleblock}
{\underline {S\'{e}rie B}:Un professeur de math\'{e}matiques d'une classe de 1\up{\`{e}re} S obtient les notes suivantes:}

\begin{center}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
Note $x_{i}$ & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\ 
\hline 
Effectifs $n_{i}$ & 1 & 4 & 5 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 2 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{exampleblock}%fin du block
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}%3




\begin{alertblock}
{\underline{S\'{e}rie C}:Le tableau ci-contre donne le nombres de personnes par m\'{e}nage en France :}
                   \begin{center}



      \begin{tabular}{|*{6}{c|}}
\hline 
Personnes par m\'{e}nage & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 et plus \\ 
\hline 
Fr\'{e}quence & 0,292 & 0,318 & 0,168 & 0,142 & 0,08 \\ 
\hline 
       \end{tabular}
                           \end{center}
                           \end{alertblock}



\begin{alertblock}{\underline{S\'{e}rie D}: Une machine d\'{e}coupe des plaques en aciers.On a mesur\'{e} la longueur des plaques d\'{e}coup\'{e}es et l'on a obtenu le tableau suivant:\\[0.5cm]}


{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}}


\begin{tabular}{|p{1.2cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline 
 \small{ Longueur de la plaque (en cm)}& [97;98[ &  [98;99[ & [99;100[&  [100;101[ & [101;102[ &  [102;103[ \\ 
 \hline 
 Nombres de plaques & 2&  34 & 66 &  102&  80&  6 \\ 
 \hline 
 \end{tabular} 
 \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%4
\frametitle{Moyenne}
Soit une s\'{e}rie statistique d'effectif total N,prenant les valeurs $x_1,x_2,...,x_p$ d'effectifs correspondants $n_1,n_2,...,n_p$. \begin{alertblock}%début
 { \textbf{D\'{e}finition}:}La moyenne de cette s\'{e}rie est not\'{e}e $\overline{x}$  et est d\'{e}finie par: 
\[\overline{x}=\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} n_i x_i}{N}=\frac{n_1x_1+n_2x_2+...+n_ix_i}{N}\]
\end{alertblock}%la fin
\end{frame}%fin du 5 eme frame
\begin{frame} %5
\begin{exampleblock}
 {Remarque:}

{ Dans le cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue, les $x_i$ correspondent au centre des classes.}

 \end{exampleblock}

{\textcolor{trustcolor}{ Application \no 1}: Calculer la Moyenne des s\'{e}ries A,B et D}

 \begin{exampleblock}
{ Propri\'{e}t\'{e}:}


 \[M=f_1 x_1+f_2 x_2+...+f_p x_p=\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i x_i\] \quad o\`{u} les\quad $f_i$ \quad sont des fr\'{e}quences

 \end{exampleblock}

 En effet,\\[2cm]




 \textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 2}: Calculer la moyenne de la  s\'{e}rie C. 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}%6
\frametitle{M\'{e}diane}
\begin{alertblock}
{D\'{e}finition: }
 On appelle m\'{e}diane d'une s\'{e}rie not\'{e}e Me, le nombre r\'{e}el qui partage la population en deux sous-s\'{e}ries de m\^{e}me effectif, c'est-\`{a}-dire le nombre tel que:
 \begin{itemize}
 \item[\textbullet]  $50 \%$ au moins de la s\'{e}rie ont une valeur inf\'{e}rieure ou \'{e}gale \`{a} Me.
 \item[\textbullet]  $50\% $  au moins de la s\'{e}rie ont une valeur sup\'{e}rieure  ou \'{e}gale \`{a} Me.
 \end{itemize}
 \end{alertblock}

 M\'{e}thode pour calculer la m\'{e}diane:
  \begin{alertblock}
{Cas d'un caract\`{e}re quantitatif discret :}
Soit N le nombre total de donn\'{e}es qu'on ordonne \underline{dans l'ordre croissant:
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet] Lorsque l'effectif total N est \textbf{impair}, la m\'{e}diane Me est le \textbf{terme central},\`{a} savoir le terme de rang $ \frac{N+1}{2}$
\item[\textbullet] Lorsque l'effectif total N est \textbf{pair}, l'usage veut que l'on choisisse pour la m\'{e}diane Me la \textbf{moyenne des deux termes centraux},\`{a} savoir les termes de rang $ \frac{N}{2}$ \quad et\quad  $\frac{N}{2}+1 $
\end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%7


\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 3:} D\'{e}terminer la m\'{e}diane des  s\'{e}ries A,B et C.\\
\begin{exampleblock}
{Cas d'un caract\`{e}re quantitatif continu}:
La m\'{e}diane correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs} (ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e} $\frac{N}{2}$ (ou 0,5 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{exampleblock}

\begin{exampleblock}
{  Remarque:   }    La m\'{e}diane n'est donc pas n\'{e}cessairement une des valeurs de s\'{e}rie.   
\end{exampleblock}
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 4:}D\'{e}terminer la m\'{e}diane de la  s\'{e}rie D.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%8
\frametitle{caract\'{e}ristiques de position non centrale: les quartiles}
\begin{alertblock}
{\textbf{D\'{e}finition}:}
On consid\`{e}re une s\'{e}rie statistique dont les valeurs du caract\`{e}re sont ordonn\'{e}es dans l'ordre croissant:
$x_1\leq x_2\leq \leq...\leq x_n $
{\begin{itemize}
\item[\centerdot]\textbf{Le premier Quartile} not\'{e} \textbf{$Q_1$} d'une s\'{e}rie statistique est la plus petite des valeurs de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins $25\%$ des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieures ou \'{e}gales.
\item[\centerdot]\textbf{Le troisi\`{e}ime Quartile } not\'{e} \textbf{$Q_3$} d'une s\'{e}rie statistique est la plus petite des valeurs de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins $75\%$ des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieures ou \'{e}gales.
\end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%9
\textbf{M\'{e}thode pour d\'{e}terminer les quartiles:}
\begin{exampleblock}{cas d'une s\'{e}rie discr\`{e}te:}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\centerdot]Lorsque l'effectif est un \textbf{multiple de 4}, les quartiles $Q_1$ et $Q_3$ sont respectivement les termes de rang \quad  $ \frac{N}{4} \quad et\quad \frac{3N}{4}$
\item[\centerdot]Lorsque l'effectif n'est \textbf{pas un multiple de 4},les quartiles $Q_1$ et $Q_3$ sontrespectivement les termes de rang $i$, le plus petit entier sup\'{e}rieur ou \'{e}gal \`{a} $\frac{N}{4}$ et de rang $j$, le plus petit entier sup\'{e}rieur ou \'{e}gal \`{a} $\frac{3N}{4}$ .
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}

\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 5:} D\'{e}terminer les quartiles des  s\'{e}ries A,B et C.

\begin{exampleblock}
{Cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue :(Les valeurs sont regroup\'{e}es par classe)}
\begin{itemize}


\item[\centerdot] $ Q_1$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{N}{4}$ (ou 0,25 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\item[\centerdot] $Q_3$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{3N}{4}$ (ou 0,75 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%10

\begin{exampleblock}
{Cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue :(Les valeurs sont regroup\'{e}es par classe)}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\centerdot] $ Q_1$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{N}{4}$ (ou 0,25 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\item[\centerdot] $Q_3$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{3N}{4}$ (ou 0,75 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%11

\begin{exampleblock}
{Cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue :(Les valeurs sont regroup\'{e}es par classe)}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\centerdot] $ Q_1$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{N}{4}$ (ou 0,25 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\item[\centerdot] $Q_3$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{3N}{4}$ (ou 0,75 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%12
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no  6:} D\'{e}terminer les quartiles de la   s\'{e}rie D.\\

\begin{block}{Remarques:}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\centerdot] De nombreuses calculatrices consid\`{e}rent les quartiles comme les m\'{e}dianes des deux s\'{e}ries onbtenues apr\`{e}s avoir partag\'{e} la s\'{e}rie initiale par sa m\'{e}diane, ce qui explique les diff\'{e}rences constat\'{e}es.Dans la pratique,ces diff\'{e}rences ont peu d'importance vu la taille des s\'{e}ries.
\item[\centerdot] De la m\^{e}me fa\c{c}on, on peut d\'{e}finir les d\'{e}ciles d'une s\'{e}rie statistique pour un d\'{e}coupage plus fin.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Les d\'{e}ciles}:
\begin{alertblock}
{D\'{e}finition:}\textbf{Le premier d\'{e}cile} est la plus petite valeur de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins 10\% des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieurres ou \'{e}gales.\\
\textbf{Le neuvi\`{e}me d\'{e}cile} est la plus petite valeur de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins 90\% des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieurres ou \'{e}gales.
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{carateristiques de disposition d'une serie statistique}
\begin{exampleblock}
{Etendue:}

D\'{e}finition:\textbf{L'\'{e}tendue} d'une s\'{e}rie not\'{e}e mesure l'\'{e}cart entre la plus grande et la plus petite valeur.
\end{exampleblock}


\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no  7:}  D\'{e}terminer l'\'{e}tendue de la s\'{e}rie A.


\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\'{e}cart interquartile}

\begin{exampleblock}%debut
{D\'{e}finitions:}\textbf{L'intervalle interquartile} est l'intervalle $[Q_1;Q_2]$. \\
\textbf{l'\'{e}cart interquartile} est $Q_3 -Q_1$.
\end{exampleblock}%fin

\begin{block}
{Remarques:}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\centerdot]l'\'{e}cart interquartile mesure la dispersion des valeurs autours de la m\'{e}diane; plus {l'\'{e}cart est petit, plus les valeurs de la s\'{e}rie appartennant \`{a} l'intervalle interquartile sont concentr\'{e}es autour de la m\'{e}diane.
\item[\centerdot]Contrairement \`{a} l'\'{e}tendue, l'\'{e}cart interquartile \'{e}limine les valeurs extr\^{e}mes qui peuvent \^{e}tre douteuse, cependant il ne tient conte que de $50\%$ de l'effectif.
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
On peut correctement r\'{e}sumer une s\'{e}rie statistique par le couple : (m\'{e}diane; intervalle interquartile)

\begin{alertblock}
{Diagramme en bo\^{i}te: (bo\^{i}tes  \`{a} moustaches ou \`{a} pattes)\\}
la bo\^{i}te (de largeur arbitraire) repr\'{e}sente $50\%$ (au moins) de l'effectif total.\\
De cette bo\^{i}te s'\'{e}tirent deux moustaches( repr\'{e}sent\'{e}es par des traits) jusqu'au minimum et au maximum.\\

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0)rectangle(1.5,1);
\draw (-2,0)rectangle(-0.5,1);
\draw (-4,0.5)--(-2,0.5);
\draw (1.5,0.5)--(4,0.5);
\draw (-4,0.4)--(-4,0.6);
\draw (4,0.4)--(4,0.6);
\draw (-4.5,-1.6)--(4.5,-1.6);
\draw(-4,-2) node[below]{Min};             
\draw(-2,-2)node[below]{$Q_1$} ;                        
\draw(-0.5,-2) node[below]{Me};                      
\draw(1.5,-2) node[below] {$Q_3$};                            
\draw(4,-2) node[below] {Max}; 
\draw (-4,-1.5)--(-4,-1.7);
\draw (-2,-1.5)--(-2,-1.7);
\draw (-0.5,-1.5)--(-0.5,-1.7);
\draw (1.5,-1.5)--(1.5,-1.7);
\draw (4,-1.5)--(4,-1.7);            
 \end{tikzpicture}                                   



\end{center}
\end{alertblock}
\begin{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
{Ces diagrammes permettent avec uniquement 5 valeurs:}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{226}] D'appr\'{e}hender la fa\c{c}on dont sont r\'{e}parties les effectifs d'une s\'{e}rie statistique

\item[\ding{226}] De comprendre les r\'{e}partitions des effectifs pour des s\'{e}ries relatives  \`{a} un m\^{e}me caract\`{e}re.
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no  9:} Repr\'{e}senter le diagramme en bo\^{i}te de la s\'{e}rie B.
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Shortly after `\frametitle{Introduction}` you have `\begin{center`, i.e. a missing close brace.

Comment: Note that composing a [minimum example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2417) enables you to solve this type of problem yourself. For difficult problems, a minimal example will result in you getting help more quickly here.

Answer (score 3):

Both compiling errors were easy to find when commenting out frame by frame. Two times you forgot a curly bracket (see my comments in the source code). Please provide minimal examples the next time.

There were still two errors left, but it compiles. These errors are pointed out in the source code below. I don't know, where this line comes from so I kicked it out.

The last three remaining warnings are OK. I get them often so don't bother.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\setbeamersize{text margin left= 0.5cm, text margin right=0.5cm}
%\setbeamersize{text margin top= 0.5cm, text margin bottom=0.5cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% this command gives the last two errors. 
% Don't know, what that is. Comment it out and search for solutions!
% Can't find the usage of that line on the internet. Just for left and right.
% Error messages: Package keyval Error: text margin top undefined.
% Error messages: Package keyval Error: text margin bottom undefined.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]% 2
\frametitle{Introduction }

Dans tout ce chapitre,nous prendrons comme exemple les 4 s\'{e}ries suivantes :

    \begin{exampleblock}
    {\underline {S\'{e}rie B}:Un professeur de math\'{e}matiques d'une classe de 1\up{\`{e}re} S obtient les notes suivantes:}

        \begin{center}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % You forgot the } at the end of the previous line
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline 
                Note $x_{i}$ & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\ 
                \hline 
                Effectifs $n_{i}$ & 1 & 4 & 5 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 2 \\ 
                \hline 
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{exampleblock}%fin du block

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%6
\frametitle{M\'{e}diane}

 M\'{e}thode pour calculer la m\'{e}diane:
    \begin{alertblock}
{Cas d'un caract\`{e}re quantitatif discret :}
Soit N le nombre total de donn\'{e}es qu'on ordonne \underline{dans l'ordre croissant:}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% You forgot the } at the end of the previous line
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[\textbullet] Lorsque l'effectif total N est \textbf{impair}, la m\'{e}diane Me est le \textbf{terme central},\`{a} savoir le terme de rang $ \frac{N+1}{2}$
            \item[\textbullet] Lorsque l'effectif total N est \textbf{pair}, l'usage veut que l'on choisisse pour la m\'{e}diane Me la \textbf{moyenne des deux termes centraux},\`{a} savoir les termes de rang $ \frac{N}{2}$ \quad et\quad  $\frac{N}{2}+1 $
        \end{itemize}
    \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**More mistakes**

- All `\item[\centerdot]` have to be replaced by `\item[$\centerdot$]`
- In the third last frame (`\'{e}cart interquartile`) change both `enumerate` to `itemize`
- Same frame: One curly bracket `{` too much in `plus l'\'{e}cart est petit`
- `\textbf{$...$}` does not exist. A text command put onto a math input
- `de rang \quad  $ \frac{N}{4} \quad et\quad \frac{3N}{4}$` -- Don't mix text and inline math. Correct would be: `de rang $\frac{N}{4}$ et $\frac{3N}{4}$`
- In most titles: Wrong syntax. ":" belongs next to the word in front of it. (in France at least let space to the next char. Space before is set automatically.)
- Frame 13: ":" into the brackets. `\frametitle{Les d\'{e}ciles:}`
- Delete `\end{exampleblock}` in the end of frame 15 (the TikZ one...)
- Add `\begin{exampleblock}` to the second line of the last frame (frame 16)
- Frame 5: Don't mix display math and inline math. `$...$` inline or `\[...\]` standing alone.
- I think you can delete all `\quad` in your source
- You are mixing `\textbullet` and `$\centerdot$` for your `itemize` environments
- You are writing units with and without space or sometimes even different. Have a look on `siunitx`. It should be or `$50\,\%$` or `\SI{50}{\percent}`

**There you are:**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamersize{text margin left= 0.5cm ,text margin right=0.5cm}
\definecolor{trustcolor}{rgb}{0.22,.26,.64}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sommaire}
\tableofcontents[%
currentsection, 
pausesubsections]
\end{frame}
}
\title{Les Statistiques}
\author{}
\institute{Lyc\'{e}e Agricole Douai}
\date{}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 1
\titlepage
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks] % 2
\frametitle{Introduction}
Dans tout ce chapitre,nous prendrons comme exemple les 4 s\'{e}ries suivantes:
\begin{exampleblock}%le premier block
{\underline{S\'{e}rie A} Un chimiste a relev\'{e} la temp\'{e}rature d'un liquide lors d'une exp\'{e}rience.\\
Il a obtenu les r\'{e}sultas suivants:\\[0.5cm]}
 \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{r}}  61& 62& 63& 64& 68& 71& 73& 77& 80\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{exampleblock}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{exampleblock}
{\underline {S\'{e}rie B}: Un professeur de math\'{e}matiques d'une classe de 1\up{\`{e}re} S obtient les notes suivantes:}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrr}
\toprule
Note $x_{i}$ & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\  
Effectifs $n_{i}$ & 1 & 4 & 5 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 2 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{exampleblock}%fin du block
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 3
\begin{alertblock}
{\underline{S\'{e}rie C}: Le tableau ci-contre donne le nombres de personnes par m\'{e}nage en France:}
                   \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule 
Personnes par m\'{e}nage & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 et plus \\  
Fr\'{e}quence & 0,292 & 0,318 & 0,168 & 0,142 & 0,08 \\ 
\bottomrule 
       \end{tabular}
                           \end{center}
                           \end{alertblock}
\begin{alertblock}{\underline{S\'{e}rie D}: Une machine d\'{e}coupe des plaques en aciers.On a mesur\'{e} la longueur des plaques d\'{e}coup\'{e}es et l'on a obtenu le tableau suivant:\\[0.5cm]}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.2cm}rrrrrr}
 \toprule 
 \small{Longueur de la plaque (en \si{\centi\meter})}&$[97;98[$&$[98;99[$&$[99;100[$&$[100;101[$&$[101;102[$&$[102;103[$\\ 
  \small{Nombres de plaques} & 2&  34 & 66 &  102&  80&  6 \\ 
 \bottomrule 
 \end{tabular} 
 \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 4
\frametitle{Moyenne}
Soit une s\'{e}rie statistique d'effectif total N,prenant les valeurs $x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_p$ d'effectifs correspondants $n_1,n_2,\dots ,n_p$.
 \begin{alertblock}{\textbf{D\'{e}finition}:} 
La moyenne de cette s\'{e}rie est not\'{e}e $\overline{x}$  et est d\'{e}finie par: 
\[\overline{x}=\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} n_i x_i}{N}=\frac{n_1x_1+n_2x_2+\dots +n_ix_i}{N}\]
\end{alertblock}%la fin
\end{frame}%fin du 4 eme frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 5
\begin{exampleblock}{Remarque:}
{ Dans le cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue, les $x_i$ correspondent au centre des classes.}
 \end{exampleblock}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\textcolor{trustcolor}{ Application \no 1}: Calculer la Moyenne des s\'{e}ries A, B et D}
 \begin{exampleblock}{ Propri\'{e}t\'{e}:}
 \[M=f_1 x_1+f_2 x_2+\dots +f_p x_p=\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i x_i\]
 o\`{u} les $f_i$ sont des fr\'{e}quences
 \end{exampleblock}
 En effet,\\[2cm]

 \textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 2}: Calculer la moyenne de la  s\'{e}rie C. 
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 6
\frametitle{M\'{e}diane}
\begin{alertblock}
{D\'{e}finition: }
 On appelle m\'{e}diane d'une s\'{e}rie not\'{e}e Me, le nombre r\'{e}el qui partage la population en deux sous-s\'{e}ries de m\^{e}me effectif, c'est-\`{a}-dire le nombre tel que:
 \begin{itemize}
 \item[\textbullet]  \SI{50}{\percent} au moins de la s\'{e}rie ont une valeur inf\'{e}rieure ou \'{e}gale \`{a} Me.
 \item[\textbullet]  \SI{50}{\percent}  au moins de la s\'{e}rie ont une valeur sup\'{e}rieure  ou \'{e}gale \`{a} Me.
 \end{itemize}
 \end{alertblock}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
 M\'{e}thode pour calculer la m\'{e}diane:
 \begin{alertblock}{Cas d'un caract\`{e}re quantitatif discret:}
Soit N le nombre total de donn\'{e}es qu'on ordonne \underline{dans l'ordre croissant:}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet] Lorsque l'effectif total N est \textbf{impair}, la m\'{e}diane Me est le \textbf{terme central},\`{a} savoir le terme de rang $\frac{N+1}{2}$
\item[\textbullet] Lorsque l'effectif total N est \textbf{pair}, l'usage veut que l'on choisisse pour la m\'{e}diane Me la \textbf{moyenne des deux termes centraux},\`{a} savoir les termes de rang $ \frac{N}{2}$ et  $\frac{N}{2}+1$
\end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 7
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 3:} D\'{e}terminer la m\'{e}diane des  s\'{e}ries A, B et C.\\
\begin{exampleblock}{Cas d'un caract\`{e}re quantitatif continu:}
La m\'{e}diane correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs} (ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e} $\frac{N}{2}$ (ou 0,5 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{exampleblock}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{exampleblock}{ Remarque:}   
 La m\'{e}diane n'est donc pas n\'{e}cessairement une des valeurs de s\'{e}rie.   
\end{exampleblock}
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 4:}D\'{e}terminer la m\'{e}diane de la  s\'{e}rie D.
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 8
\frametitle{caract\'{e}ristiques de position non centrale: les quartiles}
    \begin{alertblock}
    {\textbf{D\'{e}finition}:}
    On consid\`{e}re une s\'{e}rie statistique dont les valeurs du caract\`{e}re sont ordonn\'{e}es dans l'ordre croissant:
    $x_1\leq x_2\leq \leq\dots \leq x_n $
        \begin{itemize}
        \item[\textbullet]\textbf{Le premier Quartile} not\'{e} $Q_1$ d'une s\'{e}rie statistique est la plus petite des valeurs de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins $25\%$ des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieures ou \'{e}gales.
        \item[\textbullet]\textbf{Le troisi\`{e}ime Quartile } not\'{e} $Q_3$ d'une s\'{e}rie statistique est la plus petite des valeurs de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins $75\%$ des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieures ou \'{e}gales.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 9
\textbf{M\'{e}thode pour d\'{e}terminer les quartiles:}
\begin{exampleblock}{cas d'une s\'{e}rie discr\`{e}te:}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet]Lorsque l'effectif est un \textbf{multiple de 4}, les quartiles $Q_1$ et $Q_3$ sont respectivement les termes de rang  $\frac{N}{4}$ et $\frac{3N}{4}$
\item[\textbullet]Lorsque l'effectif n'est \textbf{pas un multiple de 4},les quartiles $Q_1$ et $Q_3$ sontrespectivement les termes de rang $i$, le plus petit entier sup\'{e}rieur ou \'{e}gal \`{a} $\frac{N}{4}$ et de rang $j$, le plus petit entier sup\'{e}rieur ou \'{e}gal \`{a} $\frac{3N}{4}$ .
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 5:} D\'{e}terminer les quartiles des  s\'{e}ries A, B et C.
\begin{exampleblock}
{Cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue: (Les valeurs sont regroup\'{e}es par classe)}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet] $ Q_1$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{N}{4}$ (ou 0,25 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\item[\textbullet] $Q_3$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{3N}{4}$ (ou 0,75 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 10
\begin{exampleblock}
{Cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue: (Les valeurs sont regroup\'{e}es par classe)}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet] $ Q_1$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{N}{4}$ (ou 0,25 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\item[\textbullet] $Q_3$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{3N}{4}$ (ou 0,75 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 11
\begin{exampleblock}{Cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue: (Les valeurs sont regroup\'{e}es par classe)}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet] $ Q_1$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{N}{4}$ (ou 0,25 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\item[\textbullet] $Q_3$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{3N}{4}$ (ou 0,75 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}%12
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no  6:} D\'{e}terminer les quartiles de la   s\'{e}rie D.\\

\begin{block}{Remarques:}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet] De nombreuses calculatrices consid\`{e}rent les quartiles comme les m\'{e}dianes des deux s\'{e}ries onbtenues apr\`{e}s avoir partag\'{e} la s\'{e}rie initiale par sa m\'{e}diane, ce qui explique les diff\'{e}rences constat\'{e}es.Dans la pratique,ces diff\'{e}rences ont peu d'importance vu la taille des s\'{e}ries.
\item[\textbullet] De la m\^{e}me fa\c{c}on, on peut d\'{e}finir les d\'{e}ciles d'une s\'{e}rie statistique pour un d\'{e}coupage plus fin.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 13
\frametitle{Les d\'{e}ciles:}
\begin{alertblock}{D\'{e}finition:}\textbf{Le premier d\'{e}cile} est la plus petite valeur de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins 10\% des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieurres ou \'{e}gales.\\
\textbf{Le neuvi\`{e}me d\'{e}cile} est la plus petite valeur de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins 90\% des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieurres ou \'{e}gales.
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{carateristiques de disposition d'une serie statistique}
\begin{exampleblock}{Etendue:}
D\'{e}finition: \textbf{L'\'{e}tendue} d'une s\'{e}rie not\'{e}e mesure l'\'{e}cart entre la plus grande et la plus petite valeur.
\end{exampleblock}
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no  7:}  D\'{e}terminer l'\'{e}tendue de la s\'{e}rie A.
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 14
\frametitle{\'{e}cart interquartile}
\begin{exampleblock}{D\'{e}finitions:}
\textbf{L'intervalle interquartile} est l'intervalle $[Q_1;Q_2]$. \\
\textbf{l'\'{e}cart interquartile} est $Q_3 -Q_1$.
\end{exampleblock}%fin
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{block}{Remarques:}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet] l'\'{e}cart interquartile mesure la dispersion des valeurs autours de la m\'{e}diane; plus l'\'{e}cart est petit, plus les valeurs de la s\'{e}rie appartennant \`{a} l'intervalle interquartile sont concentr\'{e}es autour de la m\'{e}diane.
\item[\textbullet] Contrairement \`{a} l'\'{e}tendue, l'\'{e}cart interquartile \'{e}limine les valeurs extr\^{e}mes qui peuvent \^{e}tre douteuse, cependant il ne tient conte que de \SI{50}{\percent} de l'effectif.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 15
On peut correctement r\'{e}sumer une s\'{e}rie statistique par le couple: (m\'{e}diane; intervalle interquartile)

\begin{alertblock}{Diagramme en bo\^{i}te: (bo\^{i}tes  \`{a} moustaches ou \`{a} pattes)\\}
la bo\^{i}te (de largeur arbitraire) repr\'{e}sente \SI{50}{\percent} (au moins) de l'effectif total.\\
De cette bo\^{i}te s'\'{e}tirent deux moustaches( repr\'{e}sent\'{e}es par des traits) jusqu'au minimum et au maximum.\\
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0)rectangle(1.5,1);
\draw (-2,0)rectangle(-0.5,1);
\draw (-4,0.5)--(-2,0.5);
\draw (1.5,0.5)--(4,0.5);
\draw (-4,0.4)--(-4,0.6);
\draw (4,0.4)--(4,0.6);
\draw (-4.5,-1.6)--(4.5,-1.6);
\draw(-4,-2) node[below]{Min};             
\draw(-2,-2)node[below]{$Q_1$} ;                        
\draw(-0.5,-2) node[below]{Me};                      
\draw(1.5,-2) node[below] {$Q_3$};                            
\draw(4,-2) node[below] {Max}; 
\draw (-4,-1.5)--(-4,-1.7);
\draw (-2,-1.5)--(-2,-1.7);
\draw (-0.5,-1.5)--(-0.5,-1.7);
\draw (1.5,-1.5)--(1.5,-1.7);
\draw (4,-1.5)--(4,-1.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame} % 16
\begin{exampleblock}{Ces diagrammes permettent avec uniquement 5 valeurs:}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{226}] D'appr\'{e}hender la fa\c{c}on dont sont r\'{e}parties les effectifs d'une s\'{e}rie statistique
\item[\ding{226}] De comprendre les r\'{e}partitions des effectifs pour des s\'{e}ries relatives  \`{a} un m\^{e}me caract\`{e}re.
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no  9:} Repr\'{e}senter le diagramme en bo\^{i}te de la s\'{e}rie B.
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you point out what the errors were? However, some error remain, which shouldn't.

Comment: please see my comments in the source code. Two times a missing bracket (solved) and two times `text margin undefined`. The latter disappears commenting the two `\setbeamersize{}`- lines. Don't know, what their are doing.

Comment: Only the last `\setbeamersize` needs commenting, and that is because of what the error says: `text margin top` is undefined. There is no option for setting the top and bottom margin, the way there is for left and right margin. See page 76 in the manual for a list of the valid options to `\setbeamersize`.

Comment: About the colons: I believe it is common practice in French typography to have a space before `:`, so this is not actually wrong.

Comment: seems to be done by `babel` already. It's automatically in places where it is written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamersize{text margin left= 0.5cm ,text margin right=0.5cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin top= 0.5cm ,text margin bottom=0.5cm}
\definecolor{trustcolor}{rgb}{0.22,.26,.64}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sommaire}
\tableofcontents[currentsection, 
pausesubsections]
\end{frame}
}
\title{Les Statistiques}
\author{}
\institute{Lyc\'{e}e Agricole Douai}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%premier frame


\titlepage
\end{frame}%1

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]% 2
\frametitle{Introduction }


Dans tout ce chapitre,nous prendrons comme exemple les 4 s\'{e}ries suivantes :
\begin{exampleblock}%le premier block
{\underline{S\'{e}rie A}:Un chimiste a relev\'{e} la temp\'{e}rature d'un liquide lors d'une exp\'{e}rience.\\
Il a obtenu les r\'{e}sultas suivants:\\[0.5cm]}

 \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}  61& 62& 63& 64& 68& 71& 73& 77& 80\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{exampleblock}




\begin{exampleblock}
{\underline {S\'{e}rie B}:Un professeur de math\'{e}matiques d'une classe de 1\up{\`{e}re} S obtient les notes suivantes:}

\begin{center}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
Note $x_{i}$ & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\ 
\hline 
Effectifs $n_{i}$ & 1 & 4 & 5 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 2 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{exampleblock}%fin du block
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}%3




\begin{alertblock}
{\underline{S\'{e}rie C}:Le tableau ci-contre donne le nombres de personnes par m\'{e}nage en France :}
                   \begin{center}



      \begin{tabular}{|*{6}{c|}}
\hline 
Personnes par m\'{e}nage & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 et plus \\ 
\hline 
Fr\'{e}quence & 0,292 & 0,318 & 0,168 & 0,142 & 0,08 \\ 
\hline 
       \end{tabular}
                           \end{center}
                           \end{alertblock}



\begin{alertblock}{\underline{S\'{e}rie D}: Une machine d\'{e}coupe des plaques en aciers.On a mesur\'{e} la longueur des plaques d\'{e}coup\'{e}es et l'on a obtenu le tableau suivant:\\[0.5cm]}


{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}}


\begin{tabular}{|p{1.2cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline 
 \small{ Longueur de la plaque (en cm)}& [97;98[ &  [98;99[ & [99;100[&  [100;101[ & [101;102[ &  [102;103[ \\ 
 \hline 
 Nombres de plaques & 2&  34 & 66 &  102&  80&  6 \\ 
 \hline 
 \end{tabular} 
 \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%4
\frametitle{Moyenne}
Soit une s\'{e}rie statistique d'effectif total N,prenant les valeurs $x_1,x_2,...,x_p$ d'effectifs correspondants $n_1,n_2,...,n_p$. \begin{alertblock}%début
 { \textbf{D\'{e}finition}:}La moyenne de cette s\'{e}rie est not\'{e}e $\overline{x}$  et est d\'{e}finie par: 
\[\overline{x}=\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} n_i x_i}{N}=\frac{n_1x_1+n_2x_2+...+n_ix_i}{N}\]
\end{alertblock}%la fin
\end{frame}%fin du 5 eme frame
\begin{frame} %5
\begin{exampleblock}
 {Remarque:}

{ Dans le cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue, les $x_i$ correspondent au centre des classes.}

 \end{exampleblock}

{\textcolor{trustcolor}{ Application \no 1}: Calculer la Moyenne des s\'{e}ries A,B et D}

 \begin{exampleblock}
{ Propri\'{e}t\'{e}:}


 \[M=f_1 x_1+f_2 x_2+...+f_p x_p=\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i x_i\] \quad o\`{u} les\quad $f_i$ \quad sont des fr\'{e}quences

 \end{exampleblock}

 En effet,\\[2cm]




 \textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 2}: Calculer la moyenne de la  s\'{e}rie C. 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}%6
\frametitle{M\'{e}diane}
\begin{alertblock}
{D\'{e}finition: }
 On appelle m\'{e}diane d'une s\'{e}rie not\'{e}e Me, le nombre r\'{e}el qui partage la population en deux sous-s\'{e}ries de m\^{e}me effectif, c'est-\`{a}-dire le nombre tel que:
 \begin{itemize}
 \item[\textbullet]  $50 \%$ au moins de la s\'{e}rie ont une valeur inf\'{e}rieure ou \'{e}gale \`{a} Me.
 \item[\textbullet]  $50\% $  au moins de la s\'{e}rie ont une valeur sup\'{e}rieure  ou \'{e}gale \`{a} Me.
 \end{itemize}
 \end{alertblock}

 M\'{e}thode pour calculer la m\'{e}diane:
  \begin{alertblock}
{Cas d'un caract\`{e}re quantitatif discret :}
Soit N le nombre total de donn\'{e}es qu'on ordonne \underline{dans l'ordre croissant:}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet] Lorsque l'effectif total N est \textbf{impair}, la m\'{e}diane Me est le \textbf{terme central},\`{a} savoir le terme de rang $ \frac{N+1}{2}$
\item[\textbullet] Lorsque l'effectif total N est \textbf{pair}, l'usage veut que l'on choisisse pour la m\'{e}diane Me la \textbf{moyenne des deux termes centraux},\`{a} savoir les termes de rang $ \frac{N}{2}$ \quad et\quad  $\frac{N}{2}+1 $
\end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%7


\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 3:} D\'{e}terminer la m\'{e}diane des  s\'{e}ries A,B et C.\\
\begin{exampleblock}
{Cas d'un caract\`{e}re quantitatif continu}:
La m\'{e}diane correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs} (ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e} $\frac{N}{2}$ (ou 0,5 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{exampleblock}

\begin{exampleblock}
{  Remarque:   }    La m\'{e}diane n'est donc pas n\'{e}cessairement une des valeurs de s\'{e}rie.   
\end{exampleblock}
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 4:}D\'{e}terminer la m\'{e}diane de la  s\'{e}rie D.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%8
\frametitle{caract\'{e}ristiques de position non centrale: les quartiles}
\begin{alertblock}
{\textbf{D\'{e}finition}:}
On consid\`{e}re une s\'{e}rie statistique dont les valeurs du caract\`{e}re sont ordonn\'{e}es dans l'ordre croissant:
$x_1\leq x_2\leq \leq...\leq x_n $
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\centerdot$]\textbf{Le premier Quartile} not\'{e} \textbf{$Q_1$} d'une s\'{e}rie statistique est la plus petite des valeurs de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins $25\%$ des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieures ou \'{e}gales.
\item[$\centerdot$]\textbf{Le troisi\`{e}ime Quartile } not\'{e} \textbf{$Q_3$} d'une s\'{e}rie statistique est la plus petite des valeurs de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins $75\%$ des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieures ou \'{e}gales.
\end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%9
\textbf{M\'{e}thode pour d\'{e}terminer les quartiles:}
\begin{exampleblock}{cas d'une s\'{e}rie discr\`{e}te:}

\begin{itemize}
\item[$\centerdot$]Lorsque l'effectif est un \textbf{multiple de 4}, les quartiles $Q_1$ et $Q_3$ sont respectivement les termes de rang \quad  $ \frac{N}{4} \quad et\quad \frac{3N}{4}$
\item[$\centerdot$]Lorsque l'effectif n'est \textbf{pas un multiple de 4},les quartiles $Q_1$ et $Q_3$ sontrespectivement les termes de rang $i$, le plus petit entier sup\'{e}rieur ou \'{e}gal \`{a} $\frac{N}{4}$ et de rang $j$, le plus petit entier sup\'{e}rieur ou \'{e}gal \`{a} $\frac{3N}{4}$ .
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}

\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no 5:} D\'{e}terminer les quartiles des  s\'{e}ries A,B et C.

\begin{exampleblock}
{Cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue :(Les valeurs sont regroup\'{e}es par classe)}
\begin{itemize}


\item[$\centerdot$] $ Q_1$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{N}{4}$ (ou 0,25 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\item[$\centerdot$] $Q_3$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{3N}{4}$ (ou 0,75 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%10

\begin{exampleblock}
{Cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue :(Les valeurs sont regroup\'{e}es par classe)}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\centerdot$] $ Q_1$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{N}{4}$ (ou 0,25 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\item[$\centerdot$] $Q_3$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{3N}{4}$ (ou 0,75 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%11

\begin{exampleblock}
{Cas d'une s\'{e}rie continue :(Les valeurs sont regroup\'{e}es par classe)}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\centerdot$] $ Q_1$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{N}{4}$ (ou 0,25 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\item[$\centerdot$] $Q_3$ correspond \`{a} l'\textbf{abscisse} du point du \textbf{polygone des effectifs}(ou fr\'{e}quences) \textbf{cumul\'{e}(e)s croissant(e)s} d'ordonn\'{e}e $\frac{3N}{4}$ (ou 0,75 pour les fr\'{e}quences).
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%12
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no  6:} D\'{e}terminer les quartiles de la   s\'{e}rie D.\\

\begin{block}{Remarques:}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\centerdot$] De nombreuses calculatrices consid\`{e}rent les quartiles comme les m\'{e}dianes des deux s\'{e}ries onbtenues apr\`{e}s avoir partag\'{e} la s\'{e}rie initiale par sa m\'{e}diane, ce qui explique les diff\'{e}rences constat\'{e}es.Dans la pratique,ces diff\'{e}rences ont peu d'importance vu la taille des s\'{e}ries.
\item[$\centerdot$] De la m\^{e}me fa\c{c}on, on peut d\'{e}finir les d\'{e}ciles d'une s\'{e}rie statistique pour un d\'{e}coupage plus fin.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Les d\'{e}ciles}:
\begin{alertblock}
{D\'{e}finition:}\textbf{Le premier d\'{e}cile} est la plus petite valeur de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins 10\% des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieurres ou \'{e}gales.\\
\textbf{Le neuvi\`{e}me d\'{e}cile} est la plus petite valeur de la s\'{e}rie telle qu'au moins 90\% des donn\'{e}es lui soient inf\'{e}rieurres ou \'{e}gales.
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{carateristiques de disposition d'une serie statistique}
\begin{exampleblock}
{Etendue:}

D\'{e}finition:\textbf{L'\'{e}tendue} d'une s\'{e}rie not\'{e}e mesure l'\'{e}cart entre la plus grande et la plus petite valeur.
\end{exampleblock}


\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no  7:}  D\'{e}terminer l'\'{e}tendue de la s\'{e}rie A.


\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\'{e}cart interquartile}

\begin{exampleblock}%debut
{D\'{e}finitions:}\textbf{L'intervalle interquartile} est l'intervalle $[Q_1;Q_2]$. \\
\textbf{l'\'{e}cart interquartile} est $Q_3 -Q_1$.
\end{exampleblock}%fin

\begin{block}
{Remarques:}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[$\centerdot$]l'\'{e}cart interquartile mesure la dispersion des valeurs autours de la m\'{e}diane; plus l'\'{e}cart est petit, plus les valeurs de la s\'{e}rie appartennant \`{a} l'intervalle interquartile sont concentr\'{e}es autour de la m\'{e}diane.
\item[$\centerdot$]Contrairement \`{a} l'\'{e}tendue, l'\'{e}cart interquartile \'{e}limine les valeurs extr\^{e}mes qui peuvent \^{e}tre douteuse, cependant il ne tient conte que de $50\%$ de l'effectif.
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
On peut correctement r\'{e}sumer une s\'{e}rie statistique par le couple : (m\'{e}diane; intervalle interquartile)

\begin{alertblock}
{Diagramme en bo\^{i}te: (bo\^{i}tes  \`{a} moustaches ou \`{a} pattes)\\}
la bo\^{i}te (de largeur arbitraire) repr\'{e}sente $50\%$ (au moins) de l'effectif total.\\
De cette bo\^{i}te s'\'{e}tirent deux moustaches( repr\'{e}sent\'{e}es par des traits) jusqu'au minimum et au maximum.\\

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0)rectangle(1.5,1);
\draw (-2,0)rectangle(-0.5,1);
\draw (-4,0.5)--(-2,0.5);
\draw (1.5,0.5)--(4,0.5);
\draw (-4,0.4)--(-4,0.6);
\draw (4,0.4)--(4,0.6);
\draw (-4.5,-1.6)--(4.5,-1.6);
\draw(-4,-2) node[below]{Min};             
\draw(-2,-2)node[below]{$Q_1$} ;                        
\draw(-0.5,-2) node[below]{Me};                      
\draw(1.5,-2) node[below] {$Q_3$};                            
\draw(4,-2) node[below] {Max}; 
\draw (-4,-1.5)--(-4,-1.7);
\draw (-2,-1.5)--(-2,-1.7);
\draw (-0.5,-1.5)--(-0.5,-1.7);
\draw (1.5,-1.5)--(1.5,-1.7);
\draw (4,-1.5)--(4,-1.7);            
 \end{tikzpicture}                                   



\end{center}
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}
{Ces diagrammes permettent avec uniquement 5 valeurs:}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{226}] D'appr\'{e}hender la fa\c{c}on dont sont r\'{e}parties les effectifs d'une s\'{e}rie statistique

\item[\ding{226}] De comprendre les r\'{e}partitions des effectifs pour des s\'{e}ries relatives  \`{a} un m\^{e}me caract\`{e}re.
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\textcolor{trustcolor}{Application \no  9:} Repr\'{e}senter le diagramme en bo\^{i}te de la s\'{e}rie B.
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you point out what the errors were? Some errors still remain.

Comment: If you are using window, I suggest you to use TeXStudio as your IDE. It is helpful for the beginner like me. I like it the most for its auto-completion and common errors indicator features.

Comment: In my IDE, it has no problem remain @egreg